# Displaying results, in different div's from a JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript

```
var parseResponse = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    console.log (data);

    var head = "Cheapest Flight to " + document.getElementById('search_term1').value;
    var bodystuff = document.createElement('h4');
    bodystuff.innerHTML = head;
    document.getElementById('right1').appendChild(bodystuff);

    for (var i=0; i<data.results.length; i++) {
        try {
            var printDeparture = "Depart: " +
                  data.results[i].itineraries[i].outbound.flights[i].departs_at;

            var bodystuff = document.createElement('p');
            bodystuff.innerHTML = printDeparture;
            document.getElementById('right1').appendChild(bodystuff);

            console.log(printDeparture);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(data.results[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get each result printed out in a separate div (currently, I have 3 results back) but can only print out the first of the three, I have tried to increase [i] in each of the results, and changed the divs from "right1" to "left1" but nothing happens. any help?

Here is my HTML code;

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="Assets/China.png" class="pics">
    </div>
    <div class="right" id="right1">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left" id="left1">   
    </div>
    <div class="right" >
        <img src="Assets/hotel.jpg" class="pics">
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the result I get back from the API:
 Object
results
:
Array[3]
0
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object 
(hope it makes sense)

Comment: can you share the value of response?

Comment: Do you mean the results i get back from the api?

Comment: Yes the response you get from the API

Comment: added the other parts

Comment: @Ayokunly your response doesn't make sense at all. Try to summarize your response and share it properly. Thanks

Comment: Best would be to create a [mcve] demo that reproduces problem

Comment: And please add ";" after your statements.

Comment: Im really lost on how to get the information across to you guys the API response is a lot. any pointers im new to this forum

Comment: Can u clarify what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Nayish So basically i have created a loop that runs through the length of  an  API's response  and then gets information required, e.g data.results[i].itineraries[i].outbound.flights[i].departs_at.   I have then printed it out in a div called "right1". However when the result is more than one I want to specify that result 2 and 3 from the API to go to other divs not "right1"